# Making a CASE WHEN an aggregate to avoid GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've been trying to convert a CASE WHEN query in my SELECT statement into an aggregate so that I can avoid it in the GROUP BY statement. However, I cannot seem to do it properly. Eventually, I settled for a sub-query, which makes it slightly messier than I wished it would be. Would love to hear your advice and how I can improve the query to make it look neater!

```
ID | Task | Method | Worker_ID | Location  | Duration
1  | Run  |  A     |   111     |     EUR   |    15
2  | Run  |  A     |   333     |     EUR   |    13
3  | Run  |  B     |   111     |     EUR   |    10
4  | Run  |  A     |   222     |     USA   |    12
5  | Walk |  A     |   111     |     EUR   |     9
```

Was hoping it will turn out like this:

```
Task | Method | Sum_Duration | Sum_Duration_EUR | Sum_Duration_USA
Run  |   A    |      40      |      28          |       12
Run  |   B    |      10      |      10          |       null
Walk |   A    |      9       |      9           |       null
```

I manage to do this with a subquery:

```
SELECT TASK, METHOD, SUM(SUM_DURATION) AS SUM_DURATION, 
SUM(SUM_DURATION_EUR) AS SUM_DURATION_EUR,
SUM(SUM_DURATION_USA) AS SUM_DURATION_USA
FROM (SELECT TASK, METHOD, SUM(DURATION) AS SUM_DURATION,
       CASE WHEN LOCATION = 'EUR' THEN SUM(DURATION) END AS SUM_DURATION_EUR,
       CASE WHEN LOCATION = 'USA' THEN SUM(DURATION) END AS SUM_DURATION_USA
   FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE
   GROUP BY 1,2,LOCATION) T
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Is there a way I can do this without having to create a sub-query?

Big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a filtered aggregation:

```
SELECT task, method, 
       sum(sum_duration) as sum_duration, 
       sum(sum_duration) filter (where location = 'EUR') as sum_duration_eur, 
       sum(sum_duration) filter (where location = 'USA') as sum_duration_usa 
FROM example_table
GROUP BY task, method
```